# can I make webpack load images without use require()

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to make webpack serve files,so far, I can get my images by require them in my entry.js

```
require("../image/one.png");
require('./image/two.png');
```

however, if I have 100 pictures, what should I do? Is there any way to load images through GET request? so that I just need to write

```
<img src='/images/login.png'></img>
```

in my html file or css file

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found this function of webpack

```
require.context('../images');
```

now I can load everything inside images folder, still I wonder if I can omit this require at all

Comment: Where do you use those images?

Comment: in my html page, but I have to add these in js script